# UIGetScreenImage with iPhone app used on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, screenshot, compatibility

My app uses the UIGetscreenImage () method to take a Screenshot, which works perfectly fine using iPhone simulator or an iPhone.

Now I wanted to use my app, that is targeted for iPhone on my iPad too.
Doing so, the Screenshot will only be the upper right corner of the iPad display, in the size of an iPhone display.

Changing the app target to iPad would fix the problem, but screws the complete UI, so it is a rather bad fix.

You know some other way to fix the problem?

Using the UIGetScreenImage method is no problem, as it isn't targeted for the AppStore, and I like the advantage of the statusbar included in the screenshot.
But if their is no other way to fix it I can also use another method for making screenshots.

thx for your help :)